# Kernel extension not loaded due to linking error __antimain and __realmain

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave, kernel-extension

I have a kernel extension (kext) that I compiled with Xcode 9.4.1 It worked fine. Thus, I was able to load it with SIP disabled on a HighSierra machine. Now I updated to Mojave and Xcode. So I recompiled it with Xcode 10, that worked fine. But when I load the kext with `kextutuil` as before, but on Mojave (SIP disabled) it fails due to linking errors. I get following error:

```
(kernel) Allocated link buffer for kext org.mydriver.kext at 0xffffff7f9753b000 (81920 bytes).
(kernel) kxld[org.mydriver.kext]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
(kernel) kxld[org.mydriver.kext]:   __antimain
(kernel) kxld[org.mydriver.kext]:   __realmain
(kernel) Can't load kext org.mydriver.kext - link failed.
(kernel) Failed to load executable for kext org.mydriver.kext.
(kernel) Kext org.mydriver.kext failed to load (0xdc008016).
(kernel) Failed to load kext org.mydriver.kext (error 0xdc008016).
(kernel) Kext org.mydriver.kext removing all personalities naming it from the IOCatalogue.
Kernel error handling kext request - (libkern/kext) link error.
Failed to load /tmp/mydriver.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Failed to load /tmp/mydriver.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
```

Note: it is necessary that SIP is disabled, since I only have to load it on a test machine. Does anyone have a hint or know what to adjust to make it load?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings during the build & link of your kext? The missing symbols are the default start & stop functions that should be in the kext lib in the macOS SDK that's linked to your kext by default.

Comment: Yes, but nothing really related (two deprecated issues that I had before). I also set the "Module Start/Stop Routine". But apparently, I can set now any value and the compiler/linker does not complain at all. That seems strange to me.